# JavaScript Return Array Item(s) With Largest Score

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var arr = [
    ['Math', 'John', 100], 
    ['Math', 'Jake', 89], 
    ['Math', 'Amy',  93],
    ['Science', 'Jake', 89],
    ['Science', 'John', 89],
    ['Science', 'Amy',  83],
    ['English', 'John',  82],
    ['English', 'Amy',  81],
    ['English', 'Jake',  72]
]

let topScore = Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(function (o) {
 return o[2];
}))

console.log(topScore);
```

I am able to get the highest score from the list, but I need my result to be:

```
[ 
  { "Subject": "Math", 
    "Top": [
             { Name: "John", Score: 100}
           ]
  },
  { "Subject": "Science", 
    "Top": [
             { Name: "Jake", Score: 89},
             { Name: "John", Score: 89}
           ]
  },
  { "Subject": "English", 
    "Top": [
             { Name: "John", Score: 82}
           ]
  }
]
```

What I am doing:

**Get all subjects first:**

```
var allSubj = [];
  
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    let subj = item[0];
    allSubj .push(subj);
  });
```

**Get unique Subjects:**

```
var uniqueSubjects = arr .filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
```

After getting unique subjects, my next step is to filter the array by each subject.

```
uniqueSubjects.forEach(function (subj) {
  var arrStudentsBySubject = []
  arr.forEach(function (student) {
    if (student[0] === subj) {
      arrStudentsBySubject.push(student)
    }
  })
})
```

My plan is to iterate through all unique Subjects and then for each unique subject, iterate again on the original arr list. I think there must be a better way.

Comment: Sort the array by score, then return the first element.

Comment: Sorting it by score, and returning the first element would only yield the Science for John with score of 100.

Comment: When you want to group results by a value, use an object whose keys are those values.

Comment: There are no keys  in my initial array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group results by subject, create an object whose keys are the subject names. The object contains the current top scores for each subject; when you get a score that's higher, you replace it.

```js
var arr = [
  ['Math', 'John', 100],
  ['Math', 'Jake', 89],
  ['Math', 'Amy', 93],
  ['Science', 'Jake', 89],
  ['Science', 'John', 89],
  ['Science', 'Amy', 83],
  ['English', 'John', 82],
  ['English', 'Amy', 81],
  ['English', 'Jake', 72]
];

let obj = {};
arr.forEach(([subject, name, score]) => {
  obj[subject] = obj[subject] || {
    Subject: subject,
    Top: [],
    topscore: 0
  };
  if (score > obj[subject].topscore) {
    obj[subject].Top = [{
      Name: name,
      Score: score
    }];
    obj[subject].topscore = score;
  } else if (score == obj[subject].topscore) {
    obj[subject].Top.push({
      Name: name,
      Score: score
    })
  }
});

let result = Object.values(obj);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This only shows one top score per each subject. Science has two top scorers.

Comment: No it doesn't. Amy scored higher than Jake and John.

Comment: My bad. I got the scores mixed up. I modified the question and your answer still provided the relevant result.

Comment: When I change the input I get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for grouping and check if the score is greater or equal.

```js
var array = [['Math', 'John', 100], ['Math', 'Jake', 89], ['Math', 'Amy', 93], ['Science', 'Jake', 89], ['Science', 'John', 89], ['Science', 'Amy', 83], ['English', 'John', 82], ['English', 'Amy', 81], ['English', 'Jake', 72]],
    topScore = Object.values(array.reduce((r, [Subject, Name, Score]) => {
        if (!r[Subject]) r[Subject] = { Subject, Top: [{ Name, Score }] };
        else if (r[Subject].Top[0].Score < Score) r[Subject].Top = [{ Name, Score }];
        else if (r[Subject].Top[0].Score === Score) r[Subject].Top.push({ Name, Score });
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(topScore);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: There's an error on the script. The comma after the array makes the topScore declaration invalid.

Comment: @Chett No it doesn't. You can declare multiple variables in the same `let` statement, you separate them with comma.